# how to scroll two divs independently using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page layout at the link below. when i scroll the inner-window area both the divs are scrolling..

[Link to code](https://www.codeply.com/p/GtVlFnY8gn)

I want two divs(first-column, second-column) inside inner-window to scroll independently. And disable scroll if the content is within the view port height. Is that possible to do with just CSS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Add scroll to independent class and also you have to set at what `max` height you want the content to have scroll, for the example below I have used `400px` as the height, post that height you will have scroll.

**Bonus tip**

When using [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) for direction, `flex-direction:row;` is default you no need to specifically use that.

```css
.fixed-box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky-header {
  position: fixed;
}

.inner-window {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.first-column {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 400px;
}

.second-column {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row h-100">


  <div class="col-3">

    <div class="col-9 bg-warning h-100 right-window">


      <div class="inner-window">
        <div class="first-column">
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>
          <p>This is first column</p>

        </div>
        <div style="background: green" class="second-column">
          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>

          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>
          <p>This is second column</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it out, but I'd try setting `overflow-y: scroll` in the CSS file for each div. That should automatically add scroll functionality when the content height exceeds the div height (assuming you have a fixed height set). If it doesn't work, feel free to let me know. Good luck!

Comment: It still doesn't scroll independently.

Comment: Strange, it should work fine. Check Manjuboyz answer below. He wrote out the full code of what I meant. Hope that helps!